# How to extract all of original compounds if a substring is in them with re module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```
string= "'Patriots', 'corona2020','COVID-19','coronavirus','2020TRUmp','Support2020Trump','whitehouse','Trump2020','QAnon','QAnon2020',TrumpQanon"
```

`badwords = ['qanon', 'trump', 'corona', 'COVID']`

If a compound in the `string` contains the sub-string of `badwords`, then that compound must be deleted from the string. For instance, we have `COVID` in the `badwords`, then `COVID-19` should be removed in the `string`.

I tried to use `re` module like this, but failed:

```
import re

badwords = ['qanon', 'trump', 'corona', 'COVID']
string = "'Patriots', 'corona2020','COVID-19','coronavirus','2020TRUmp','Support2020Trump',Trump2020,'QAnon'"
for each in badwords:
    print(re.findall ('[0-9a-zA-Z]+'+each,string,flags=re.IGNORECASE)+\
          re.findall (each+'[0-9a-zA-Z]+',string,flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

what I want: a new string `"'Patriots','whitehouse'"` should return.

Comment: You can use `in` for each string; there is no need for a regular expression here: `if any(badword in "COVID-19" for badword in badwords):`

Comment: Is `TrumpQanon` not within single quotes like the rest of the substrings are? Also, why don't you want `corona2020` to be returned?

Comment: @JvdV sorry typos. changed coronavirus into corona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a regex that would match any of the words in the `badwords` list:

```
import re
rex_string = "(" + "|".join(badwords) + ")" # (qanon|trump|corona|COVID)

rex = re.compile(rex_string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Then, `split()` your `string` by commas to get a list that each element contains one compound word.
Next, iterate over this list and if the regex *doesn't* match the string, add it to your new list of words.
Finally, we can join the new list of words into a single string using `str.join()`

```
words_list = string.split(",")
new_list = []

for word in words_list:
    if rex.search(word) is None:
        # Didn't find a match
        new_list.append(word)

new_string = ",".join(new_list)
```

which gives us the string:

```
"'Patriots','whitehouse'"
```

If you were so inclined, you could write the loop as a one liner:

```
new_list = [word for word in string.split(",") if rex.search(word) is None]
```

Or,

```
new_string = ",".join(word for word in string.split(",") if rex.search(word) is None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am converting every word to upper(or can be lower) so can match every similar word without small cap or capital difference with `find`

```
badwords=['qanon','trump','coronavirus','COVID']
string= "'Patriots', 'corona2020','COVID-19','coronavirus','2020TRUmp','Support2020Trump','whitehouse','Trump2020','QAnon','QAnon2020',TrumpQanon"
new_string = string.split(',')

for bad_word in badwords:
 new_string = [every_word for every_word in new_string if every_word.upper().find(bad_word.upper()) == -1]
     
 
string_without_bad_word = ','.join(new_string) #"'Patriots', 'corona2020','whitehouse'"
```